# Recommendations for DirectShow filters to test against that generate dynamic media types (other than standard video renderers)

Tags: directshow

I'm trying to make my filters robust against dynamic media type changes but I haven't found any suitable filters to test against.

I've already implemented support for dynamic format changes in the video renderer but I'm looking for filters (and supporting media files if needed) which generate the following dynamic media type changes (in order of priority). Standard Microsoft filters included in Windows would be ideal but I'm happy to consider others, especially if open source.

1. [QueryAccept (Downstream)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377488(v=vs.85).aspx)
2. [QueryAccept (Upstream)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377489(v=vs.85).aspx)
3. [ReceiveConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377497(v=vs.85).aspx)

Just to clarify I'm **not** looking for video renderer filters as I already test against these ([Handling Format Changes from the Video Renderer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388901(v=vs.85).aspx)